# For designing a runway, what are the largest cargo airplanes in use?

Tags: runways, airport-design, cargo

I am working on a project where I have to design a runway for large cargo planes and I need to know what kind of planes I should assume would land there.

Comment: It depends on a lot of factors, such as the number of packages to be transported, available runway length, local climate, political connection with other countries, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kevin, however i just need to know what cargo planes are most commonly used today.

Comment: If you plan around the latest variant of the 747, everything else in use will pretty well be taken care of.  UPS flies 747s, FedEx flies the MD-11, which is similar. And both fly other, smaller jets as well.

Comment: Are you asking for statistics to support one type or another? That might be hard to offer. It would be easier to give prominent examples. In my experience, I see the A300, B757, B767, and B747 in frequent use. For example, UPS [operates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPS_Airlines#Fleet) 75 B757s, 59 B767s, 52 A300s, etc. FedEx [operates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FedEx_Express#Fleet) 119 B757s, 68 A300s, 59 MD-11s, etc. Atlas [operates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_Air#Fleet) 45 B747s, etc. ABX [operates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABX_Air#Fleet) 37 B767s.

Comment: @andrew please specify if you mean civilian or military cargo planes.

Answer (score 9):

### Size doesn't matter.*

If you are designing a runway, then you should get familiar with [ACN and PCN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_classification_number).

> The **aircraft classification number** (ACN) is a number expressing the relative effect of an aircraft on the runway pavement for a specified standard subgrade category.

* There can be the largest aircraft out there, but it may have a lot of tires, so the force it will exert [per tire] on the pavement might be lower than that of a smaller plane (e.g., A380 and MD-11).

From the linked Wikipedia article, the [MD-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_MD-11) stands out as the harshest on pavements (after discounting non-freighter aircraft).

[image]

---

**Runway length, and wingspan**

In most cases, aircraft are loaded according to the available length, not the other way around. [Not all airports](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/40951) that handle 747s have 11,000-foot [corrected length] runways.

For the wingspan (or main gear span), the categories are defined by [ICAO Aerodrome Reference Code](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/ICAO_Aerodrome_Reference_Code).

> Element 2 of the Code is derived from the most restrictive of either the aircraft wingspan or the aircraft outer main gear wheel span.

[image]

Comment: I beg to differ - side _does_ matter. It takes more runway to get a 747 off the ground than, say a 707. (Not that there are many 707s hauling cargo these days...) An AN-225 may be able to take off from a gravel strip, but it's going to be a _long_ one... Yes the ACN is an important factor, but runway length and width are as important and don't seem to be listed in the chart you showed a snippet of. (Also, making it clear where the image came from would be good.)

Comment: My bad, I missed that part of the sentence. Updates look good!

Comment: So what do they do for aircraft with an 80-meter-or-more wingspan and/or a 16-meter-or-more outermaingearwheelspan?

Comment: @Sean: When/if such a civil plane with the purpose of international travel is made, then maybe they'll add G – note that the F code is recent ;)

Answer (score 8):

The C5 Galaxy is a large pure cargo plane, with the nose able to swing wide open.

[image]
[Image source](https://foxtrotalpha.jalopnik.com/what-it-is-like-to-fly-the-americas-biggest-jet-the-ga-1727650088)

The Ukranians make larger cargo planes than the C-5, nicknamed the vodka burners here in Australia. Slighty larger than the C-5 is the Antonov AN124.

[image]
[Image source](https://forum.flightgear.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=10540)

And the largest of them all, the B747 freighter and the Antonov AN225.

[image]
[Image source](http://www.aerospace-technology.com/projects/boeing747-400f/)

[image]
[Image source](http://moneyinc.com/exactly-how-big-and-costly-is-super-plane-antonov-an-225-mriya/)

The pure cargo planes have swing noses which allows for sticking big chunks of cargo straight in. We had a look at air freighting a simulator some time ago, and a regular freighter 747 could not do it, too bulky for the side loading set-up. Only the swing nose guys could manage, requiring airport facilities that could handle oversize freight.

A comparison between sizes of 747 and An225 is found on [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-225_Mriya)

[image]
[Image source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Giant_planes_comparison_-_Updated.svg)

Comment: I thought all C-5s were retired? But then again I've also heard of plans to return some of them to service...

Comment: Yeah they're C-5M Super Galaxy's now.

Comment: On the C-5, the ***cockpit*** doesn't swing open; it stays put. It's the ***nose*** of the C-5 swings open.

Comment: A bit of a Duh error, have rectified.

Comment: C-5 in picture: NOM