# Is there something like a table of aircraft required runway lengths?

Tags: landing, aircraft-performance, takeoff, runways, v-speeds

I'm looking for a chart showing the minimum length a runway can be for various aircraft to land and take off.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: You'll have to use the individual performance charts for the particular aircraft in question using the ambient atmospheric conditions for the particular day in question, usually computing both the ground roll length and obstacle clearance lengths for a particular takeoff technique.

Comment: It's aircraft specific as part of the operating limitations

Answer (score 7):

Such table would not be useful at all. As the required runway length varies with the aircraft weight, pressure altitude, temperature, aircraft configuration, runway slope, condition (wet, dry), wind, etc.

Examples:

- A 7000-foot runway can handle a 747, but listing the 747 under aircraft that can takeoff from 7000' runways does not say how big the weight penalty will be.
- A 7000' runway at sea-level is longer than 7000' at a high altitude airport.

I'm afraid you won't find such list.

---

Related:

- [For designing a runway, what are the largest cargo airplanes in use?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/41144/14897)
- [How can a Boeing 747 takeoff from Princess Juliana 7,546 ft runway?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/40951/14897)

Answer (score 0):

Aircraft manufacturers issue the manual of aircraft characteristics of each type of aircraft. The reference documents provide airlines, MROs, airport planners and operators with the general dimensions of the aircraft, the necessary information for ramp, servicing operations or maintenance preparation. Minimum length for take-off and landing often include in it.

Here is the link for the documents for several major Airliner manufacturer:

- [Airbus](http://reference%20documents%20provide%20airlines,%20MROs,%20airport%20planners%20and%20operators%20with%20the%20general%20dimensions%20of%20the%20aircraft,%20as%20well%20as%20the%20necessary%20information%20for%20ramp,%20servicing%20operations%20or%20maintenance%20preparation.)
- [Boeing](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/airports/plan_manuals.page)
- [Bombardier](https://customer.aero.bombardier.com/)
- [Embraer](https://www.embraercommercialaviation.com/media-downloads/#51-apm)