# What is that to and fro moving thing?

Tags: jet-engine, turbofan, bleed-air

This [video](https://youtu.be/arqLegWUblg?list=PLE5I9ZZNPu1PjuwJl0HnkLknEbcl-2PGs&t=627) by AgentJayZ is the maintenance and repair of AI-25 turbofan. What is that thing moving due to applying certain pressure to that pipe? Can anyone describe its purpose and how it works?

[image: This is what I am talking about]

Comment: Reminder: please no answers in comments.

Comment: Related: [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/46667/3201) and [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48373/3201). I can't say more.

Comment: @mins I am not sure I get an answer on how do bleed valve actually works? How can it sense now it is time to suck before the occurrence of the stall?

Comment: @Auberron Comments are not for answers, not even partial ones or assumptions for answers. See the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). If you want to have an informal chat about your question, use a [chat room](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms).

Comment: once again; comments are for seeking clarification and improving the question. Do not post pseudo answers in comments. they will be deleted. If you wish to answer the question, do so in the answer box below.

Comment: @Jamiec: You're right, it's in the book, but yourself you also like to comment, provide anecdotes and even jokes, and sometimes [clues for the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4M5X.png). And frankly I don't see a problem, these elements help others to provide more complete answers. If some cleaning is needed it's always possible to do it later.

Comment: @mins If im guilty of it, I would expect those to be deleted also. I am human, I do make mistakes.